# How does the same source code generate binaries for different platforms?

Tags: compilation, build-process, multiplatform, binaries

Many multi-platform applications seem to have common source code. How do builds generate platform specific binaries?
Is it possible to build say, a windows binary on linux or mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible if you have an appropriate cross-compiler and libraries.  For example, many programs which are available on both Linux and Windows use the MinGW toolchain on Windows, which includes a library that emulates POSIX functions using Win32 functions.

Answer (score 0):

The platform a binary is compiled to run on depends on the compiler and generally, one can have the compiler compile for a target system. To that end, yes it is generally possible to compile for a system other than the one you are running on. Though you are usually better off compiling for a target system on that system.